# Change html/jsp contents dynamically without restart the server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-boot

Am developing a application in which html content of the pages are able to change dynamically. From my application itself user can able to change their html pages using drag and drop form(which is used to design pages).

Once the page is edited and saved successfully, I need to restart the server to reflect the changes in browser which is hurting lot.

I want to build this solution without restart the server.

**What I found:**
Number 1: I try to have my html pages in DB or file and in run time, i will read from that and render in browser.

Problems:

1: performance 
2: HTML code is working fine in out.print() But JSP code are showing as code itself in browser.

Is there any other solution available for to fix this or any existing framework available?

Comment: with javascript you can edit your html

Comment: not with javascript. If I edit abc.jsp then save, it need to reflect to all the user who are all using the application. @gen.Strash

Comment: i think you want to build a CMS. go for approach will be to store in DB only. many commercially available CMS uses DB to store their page content and their performance is quite good. as of matter of your java code is concerned,  you need to provide that functionality with javascript. go with AJAX or something to execute if some java is must to run.